# ActiveX "no button" with JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

i have a JS calling activex to create a file.

```
var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
if (object != null) {
    var file = object.CreateTextFile("C:\\" + str2 + ".csv", false);
}
```

This pops'up a Activex Box with YES/NO button. The YES button works fine, my script is executed.

My problem is the NO button, it returns a IE warning:

> Automation server can't create object.

Is there a way to handle the NO button?

Comment: What does the box say, besides Yes/No? Did you actually read what it's asking?

Comment: i'am working with a french version of IE, a quick translation would be : A activex control is trying to run on this page, would you like to activate it (YES / NO)

Answer (score 2):

This is an important security feature. Arbitrary JavaScript code cannot access the filesystem, so to do so, you are using ActiveX. But because this is doing something so dangerous, the user needs to be asked if it's OK, which is the pop-up you're seeing.

If the user chooses "No," this means they don't trust your code. You have to just accept that.

You could try adding something like "Please click yes when IE warns you about ActiveX; I promise I won't hurt your computer too much!" But of course it's up to the user whether or not they'll take your word for it.

Comment: i don't really mind people clicking the NO button.

The probleme is that when it is clicked, IE returns a javascript error, since i don't know how to handle the "no" reply.